# Add a fee to an order programmatically in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, fee

I'm creating Woocommerce totals 'on-the-fly' as my cart items are imported from another CMS.

Currently **I am having trouble setting a custom 'fee' for each order**, then marking the order as 'on-hold':

```
                $order->set_date_created($creation_tsz);

                $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
                $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
                $order->set_currency('GBP');

                $order->add_fee('Imported Total', $imported_total_here);
                $order->set_fee();

                $order->calculate_totals();

                $order->update_status('on-hold');
```

Any track on this will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of problem, give us the error you get. And code of  set_fee function.

Comment: ah, is set_fee not a standard function? perhaps thats where i was led astray. for the moment i add_fee and calculate the totals, but when i view the order 0.00 is present for both the fee and total. so order = 0.00

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> The `WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order`  method [`add_fee()` is deprecated](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order.html#94-123) and `set_fee()` method doesn't exist for the `WC_Order` Class *(exist only for `WC_Cart` and `WC_API_Orders` classes)*.

**To add a Fee to an order programmatically** since Woocommerce 3, it's a bit more complicated. There are some parameters to set as the Fee name, the tax status, the tax class *(if needed)* and the fee amount *(excl. taxes)*.

Also to make the tax calculations, depending on the taxes settings, you will need to set an array containing at minima the customer country code *(if the taxes are based on the country)*

Let say that the fee amount variable name is `$imported_total_fee` in the code below:

```
$order->set_date_created($creation_tsz);

$order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
$order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
$order->set_currency('GBP');

## ------------- ADD FEE PROCESS ---------------- ##

// Get the customer country code
$country_code = $order->get_shipping_country();

// Set the array for tax calculations
$calculate_tax_for = array(
    'country' => $country_code, 
    'state' => '', 
    'postcode' => '', 
    'city' => ''
);

// Get a new instance of the WC_Order_Item_Fee Object
$item_fee = new WC_Order_Item_Fee();

$item_fee->set_name( "Fee" ); // Generic fee name
$item_fee->set_amount( $imported_total_fee ); // Fee amount
$item_fee->set_tax_class( '' ); // default for ''
$item_fee->set_tax_status( 'taxable' ); // or 'none'
$item_fee->set_total( $imported_total_fee ); // Fee amount

// Calculating Fee taxes
$item_fee->calculate_taxes( $calculate_tax_for );

// Add Fee item to the order
$order->add_item( $item_fee );

## ----------------------------------------------- ##

$order->calculate_totals();

$order->update_status('on-hold');

$order->save();
```

Tested and perfectly works.

Comment: Where will this code be added? I'm working on similar project where i need to add a processing fee dynamically on order created manually...

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Solution not working with negative value. Actually, I want to add discount on order object. is there any way to add negative fees and non-taxable fees.