# Add a shipping to an order programmatically in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, shipping-method

I've been trying numerous solutions to programmatically set the price of shipping (per order) via Woocommerce. I'm having no luck

I have tried overwriting the meta value for the item:

```
            update_post_meta( $woo_order_id, '_order_shipping', $new_ship_price );
```

Also tried something along the lines of this [Question/Answer][1]

```
                    $item_ship = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();

                    $item_ship->set_name( "flat_rate" );
                    $item_ship->set_amount( $new_ship_price );
                    $item_ship->set_tax_class( '' );
                    $item_ship->set_tax_status( 'none' );


                    // Add Shipping item to the order
                    $order->add_item( $item_ship );
```

But neither seem to work.
Any pointers most welcome.

---

Similar thread: [Add a fee to an order programmatically in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603746/add-a-fee-to-an-order-programmatically-in-woocommerce-3?noredirect=1#comment94070357_53603746)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To handle this in Woocommerce 3+ use the following (from a `WC_Order` Order  object `$order`):

```
## ------------- ADD SHIPPING PROCESS ---------------- ##

// Get the customer country code
$country_code = $order->get_shipping_country();

// Set the array for tax calculations
$calculate_tax_for = array(
    'country' => $country_code,
    'state' => '', // Can be set (optional)
    'postcode' => '', // Can be set (optional)
    'city' => '', // Can be set (optional)
);

// Optionally, set a total shipping amount
$new_ship_price = 5.10;

// Get a new instance of the WC_Order_Item_Shipping Object
$item = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();

$item->set_method_title( "Flat rate" );
$item->set_method_id( "flat_rate:14" ); // set an existing Shipping method rate ID
$item->set_total( $new_ship_price ); // (optional)
$item->calculate_taxes($calculate_tax_for);

$order->add_item( $item );

$order->calculate_totals();

$order->update_status('on-hold');

// $order->save(); // If you don't update the order status
```

Tested an works.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you once again for your help, so clear and concise.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I was searching this code. Really superb man! 100% worked.

Comment: Is it also possible to replace a shipping method? I have try this but now I get 2 shipping methods on each order 

`function myfunc($order_id){
 $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
 $item = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();
 $item->set_method_title( "Ophalen" );
 $item->set_method_id( "local_pickup:2" );
 $order->remove_item('flat_rate:1');
 $order->add_item( $item );
 $order->save();
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'myfunc');`

Comment: @Jop Get the data from the shipping method you want to change, to insert it as a new one( with your changes), then remove the old one before inserting the new one. It's easier this way.

Comment: Great, this is what I needed for my unit testing.  When you say: 

$item->set_method_id( "flat_rate:14" ); // set an existing Shipping method rate ID

How can I add a shipping method?  In my unit test I do not have a shimming method defined.