# Set the shipping method in WooCommerce Subscriptions renewal orders

Tags: php, woocommerce, methods, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

When a user buys a product with the recurrent option which create an order each month, there is no shipping methods set. Only the parent order has the shipping method, and all child orders doesn't have shipping.

I would like to add the parent shipping method to all child orders while a recurrent order is created.

Here the code I tried but not working, I would like to add the shipping method of the parent when the child order is created.

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'add_colissimo_method', 10, 1);

function add_colissimo_method($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

  
    if ($order->get_shipping_method()) {
        return; 
    }


        $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order($renewal_order_id);

        if (!empty($subscriptions)) {
    
            $parent_order_id = $subscriptions[0]->get_parent_id();

            if (!empty($parent_order_id)) {
                $parent_order = wc_get_order($parent_order_id);
                $parent_shipping_method = $parent_order->get_shipping_method();
                update_post_meta($renewal_order_id, '_shipping_method', $parent_shipping_method);
            }
     }

    $order->save();
    
}
```

Comment: This is the wrong hook. Use this documentation - https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/ . This hook woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete is what you need. From there you can access the order data and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing this in the right way, and you need to use [WC Subscriptions filter hooks](https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/filter-reference/).

Try the following instead *(code is commented)*:

```php
add_filter( 'wcs_new_order_created', 'add_shipping_items_to_renewal_orders', 10, 3 );
function add_shipping_items_to_renewal_orders( $order, $subscription, $type ) {
    // Targeting renewal orders only
    if ( $type === 'renewal_order' ) {
        // Get the parent order (initial order)
        $parent_order = $subscription->get_related_orders('all', 'parent');
        $parent_order = reset($parent_order);

        // Set the array for tax calculations
        $calculate_tax_for = array(
            'country'   => $parent_order->get_shipping_country(),
            'state'     => $parent_order->get_shipping_state(),
            'postcode'  => $parent_order->get_shipping_postcode(),
            'city'      => $parent_order->get_shipping_city(),
        );

        // Loop through parent order "shipping" items
        foreach( $parent_order->get_items('shipping') as $parent_item ) {
            $item  = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping(); // create a new empty order item "shipping"
            $item->set_method_title( $parent_item->get_method_title() ); // set the existing Shipping method title
            $item->set_method_id( $parent_item->get_method_id() ); // set an existing Shipping method rate ID
            $item->set_total( $parent_item->get_total() );  // set an existing Shipping method total
            $item->calculate_taxes( $calculate_tax_for );  // Calculate taxes for the item

            $order->add_item( $item ); // Add the shipping item to the renewal order
        }
        $order->calculate_totals(); // recalculate totals and save
    }
    return $order;
}
```

It should work.

Related: [Add update or remove WooCommerce shipping order items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56038530/add-update-or-remove-woocommerce-shipping-order-items/56041391#56041391)

---

Comment: It works perfectly thank you so much !

Last question, how can i set free taxes for the shipping because i would like to give free shipping for renewal orders.

Comment: The code without taxes does not work, but i'll still calculate taxes and avoid user to select the shipping that make him pay taxes, i'm trying to deactivate a shipping method when having a subscription in my cart but i don't know how

Comment: There is maybe a misunderstanding, i would like to remove a specific shipping method and keep the others. I currently have three methods and i'd like to remove the chronopost one.

Comment: What are the shipping rate ID(s) for those Chronopost shipping method(s)?… You can get this rate ID(s) by inspecting the radio buttons input fields and get the attributte **name** value.

Comment: Maybe it should be better if you ask a new question, as this is something different than your initial question. Then you can notify me here, I will try to answer it.

Comment: Here the new question i created : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77095984/remove-a-shipping-method-when-a-woocommerce-subscription-is-selected.