# Hide a shipping method when a subscription is in cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions, shipping-method

I have enabled WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin in My WooCommerce shop.

Following [Set the shipping method in WooCommerce Subscriptions renewal orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77088176/set-the-shipping-method-in-woocommerce-subscriptions-renewal-orders/77088639#77088639) answer code to my previous question, I would like to remove the Chronopost shipping method when a user has a product with a subscription on his cart.

Currently there are three different shipping methods and I want to keep the Colissimo domicile and Point Relais only.

Here are the shipping rate keys for each shipping method:

- Colissimo domicile (gratuit): `lpc_nosign:6`
- Chronopost domicile 24h: `chrono13`
- Point relais (gratuit)"; `chronorelais`

[image: In red you can see the method that i want to delete when the subscription is selected]

Answer (score 1):

To hide a specific shipping method when there is a subscription product in cart, use:

```php
// Conditional function: Check if cart has a subscription
function has_subscription_product( $cart_contents ) {
    foreach ( $cart_contents as $item ) {
        if ( $item['data']->is_type( array('subscription', 'subscription_variation') ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hide shipping  method conditionally
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_package_shipping_rates', 10, 2 );
function filter_package_shipping_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    $targeted_id = 'chrono13'; // Here define the targeted shipping method rate ID

    // If there is a subscription in cart
    if( has_subscription_product( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) && isset($rates[$targeted_id]) ) {
        unset($rates[$targeted_id]); // Hide the shipping method
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

**Important:** You will have to empty your cart to refresh shipping method cache.

[Sort shipping methods displayed in WooCommerce Cart and Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77019617/sort-shipping-methods-displayed-in-woocommerce-cart-and-checkout/77021056#77021056)

Comment: I added the code to functions.php but the chrono shipping method still visible.

I have another filter that call the woocommerce_package_rate with higher priority (20).

I tried to add the condition in this filter but this is not working too.

Comment: Oups! sorry: I have tested and updated the code… Now it works.

Comment: The updated code does not work too.

Comment: Sorry, but my code works, and you didn't give enough details when I am looking to your answer code. I will not answer any of your questions again.

Comment: Maybe your code is working but I have a lot of conflicts in my code due to the amount of function that i added. I found another solution that fit better for my code. I'm not used to post on stackoverflow, i'm sorry if i'm doing the things wrong

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to resolve this by using the following code :

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $product       = $cart_item[ 'data' ];
    $supports_args = array(
      'cart_item'     => $cart_item,
      'cart_item_key' => $cart_item_key
    );

    $produit_abo_key[] = WCS_ATT_Product_Schemes::get_subscription_scheme( $product );
}

if (!in_array(FALSE,$produit_abo_key)) $has_free_shipping = true;  

    if( $has_free_shipping ){
        if ($rate->method_id == 'chrono13') {
            unset($rates["chrono13"]);
        }
    }
```