# Customize WooCommerce order shipping item on specific order status change

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders, shipping-method

I am trying in WooCommerce admin order edit pages, when order status is changed to "ready-to-shop", to change shipping item name to "LCS Express". Also, I am trying to update shipping selected options, when editing order shipping items, to include "LCS Express" shipping method

Here is my code:

```php
function customize_order_item_display($product, $item, $item_id) {
    // Get the order ID
    $order_id = $item->get_order_id();

    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Check if the payment status is "ready-to-ship"
    if ($order->get_status() === 'ready-to-ship') {
        // Modify the shipping method
        $new_shipping_method = 'LCS Express'; // Replace with your desired shipping method

        // Get the shipping method data
        $shipping_method_data = $item->get_data()['shipping'];

        // Set the new shipping method name
        $shipping_method_data['name'] = $new_shipping_method;

        // Set the new shipping method ID
        $shipping_method_data['method_id'] = sanitize_title($new_shipping_method);

        // Update the item with the modified shipping method data
        $item->set_props(array('shipping' => $shipping_method_data));
        $item->save();

        // Modify the shipping input fields using JavaScript
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                // Set the shipping method name in the input field
                $('input.shipping_method_name').val('<?php echo esc_js($new_shipping_method); ?>');
                
                // Set the shipping method ID in the select field
                $('select.shipping_method').val('<?php echo esc_js($shipping_method_data['method_id']); ?>');
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'customize_order_item_display', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in your code and you are not using the correct hook and the correct way to do it. Always use [`WC_Order_Item`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.6/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-item.php) and [`WC_Order_Item_Shipping`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.6/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-item-shipping.php) available setter methods instead, to make changes to order "shipping" item(s).

It is better to use one of [the dedicated transition order status hooks](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.6/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php#L411), to make changes to the order, when the order status is changed to 'ready-to-ship'.

Try the following:

```php
// Customize order shipping item(s)
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_ready-to-ship', 'customize_order_shipping_item_on_ready_to_ship', 10, 2 );
function customize_order_shipping_item_on_ready_to_ship( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Iterating through order shipping items
    foreach( $order->get_items( 'shipping' ) as $item_id => $item ) {
        $method_name = __('LCS Express'); // New shipping method name 

        $item->set_name($method_name);
        $item->set_method_title($method_name);
        $item->set_method_id( sanitize_title($method_name) );
        $item->save();
    }
}

// On edit order shipping item, change 'lcs-express' selected option text to 'LCS Express'
add_action('admin_footer', 'wc_order_admin_footer_script', 10);
function wc_order_admin_footer_script() {
    if( isset($_GET['page'], $_GET['action']) && 'wc-orders' === $_GET['page'] && 'edit' === $_GET['action'] ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        if( $('select.shipping_method').val() === 'lcs-express' ) {
            $('select.shipping_method option[value=lcs-express]').text('LCS Express');
        }
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

Related:

- [Get orders shipping items details in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102428/get-orders-shipping-items-details-in-woocommerce-3/46106700#46106700)
- [Add update or remove WooCommerce shipping order items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56038530/add-update-or-remove-woocommerce-shipping-order-items/56041391#56041391)
- [Change shipping method programmatically from existing WooCommerce order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61814206/change-shipping-method-programmatically-from-existing-woocommerce-order/61938180#61938180)